# Find all rows using some Unicode range (such as Cyrillic characters) with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

How do I find all rows of a PostgreSQL table that contain characters in some Unicode range, such as Cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 17):

Figured it out! For Cyrillic:

```
SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE (title SIMILAR TO '%[\u0410-\u044f]%')
```

I got the range from http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/cyrillicchart.html. The characters have hex entities `&#x0410;` to `&#x044F;`, which are also my numbers above.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the [pgpcre](https://github.com/petere/pgpcre) extension, you can use this expression:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE title ~ pcre '\p{Cyrillic}';
```