# How to get only Cyrillic characters from a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unicode

I would to find all the rows of a PostgreSQL table which have Cyrillic characters. I tried to use this query:  `SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE (title SIMILAR TO '%[\u0410-\u044f]%')`, which I take here:
 [Find all rows using some Unicode range (such as Cyrillic characters) with PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789604/find-all-rows-using-some-unicode-range-such-as-cyrillic-characters-with-postgr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

It seems to work, but other then the Cyrillic values, I also get some Latin values. How is it possible? I think that maybe, even if I'm writing Latin letters, if I use a keyboard with Cyrillic characters, some of them could be read as Cyrillic.

Anyway, I'm using this DB on a Java project. Does exist a more efficient solution via code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reqular expression.
The function name in PostgreSQL is `REGEXP_MATCHES`.

Documentation:

- [PostgreSQL REGEXP_MATCHES Function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-regexp_matches/)
- [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)
- [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

Another solution is to use the true/false operator: `~`.

Documentation: [Using regexps in PostgreSQL](http://blog.lerner.co.il/regexps-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

use the same mask:

```
t=# select regexp_replace('pol 398Родное Луговое abc 123','[^\u0410-\u044f]','','g');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 РодноеЛуговое
(1 row)
```

Comment: Now it's a bit better, but the problem is that when I have for example a string containing both Latin (or numbers) and Cyrillic characters, I will obtain as result just the part in Cyrillic. What I would, is the entire string.