# ActiveRecord find elements with Cyrillic field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, cyrillic

I want to find all users with Cyrillic names. How can I do it with ActiveRecord?

Non ActiveRecord solution is here: `User.all.select{ |user| user.name.match(/\p{Cyrillic}/) }`. Unfortunatelly regexp `/\p{Cyrillic}/` doesn't work with sql.

UPDATE: from the discussion below I realize that I need solutions for Postgres and MySQL. 
For postgres it could be `SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE (title SIMILAR TO '%[\u0410-\u044f]%')`

from [Find all rows using some Unicode range (such as Cyrillic characters) with PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789604/find-all-rows-using-some-unicode-range-such-as-cyrillic-characters-with-postgr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777720/rails-sql-regular-expression

Comment: @JagdeepSingh It is not a duplicate of that link definitely. Author did not ask for "how to use Regexp in SQL" at all.

Comment: Alex, you have to add your DB in tags, because answer is DB specific. I.e. for Postgresql - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789604/find-all-rows-using-some-unicode-range-such-as-cyrillic-characters-with-postgr

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk thanks for Postgres solution. I'd like to get a not DB specific answer, which could be used for MySQL and Postgres as well ;)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh thanks for the link, but it's only about regexp in ActiveRecord query. I need a specific one.

Comment: Alex, there is no regexp standard in SQL. Each DB implements it with its own keywords and (even worse) own regexp libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780194/how-to-regex-in-a-sql-query

Comment: And even solution from Postrge example is not perfect, because it depends on string data `encoding`, which can differs.